# List View doesn't populate using Firebase

Tags: java, android

I am just having a problem when populating my list view. I think I know what's the problem since I tested it multiple times and it seems like the path for retrieving my data is actually the user store and not the bets but I don't seem to get where does the path come from. I was looking back at the methods and it seems that the path would be the DatabaseReference although my reference in the class is just standard

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Here is my Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Bets> bets;
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); //Getting currently logged user
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    String hours;
    String samount;


    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bets> bets) {
        this.c = c;
        this.bets = bets;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return bets.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int itemid) {
        return itemid;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view == null)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,viewGroup,false);
        }

        TextView condition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.conditionList);
        TextView place = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.placeList);
        TextView amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amountList);

        final Bets bet = (Bets) this.getItem(position);

        condition.setText(bet.getCondition());
        place.setText(bet.getPlace());
        String setamount = String.valueOf(bet.getAmount());
        amount.setText(setamount);
        hours = String.valueOf(bet.getHours());
        samount = String.valueOf(bet.getAmount());


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                openDetailList(bet.getCreator(),bet.getCondition(),bet.getPlace(),hours,samount,bet.getJoined(),bet.getCreatorUid(),bet.getJoinedUid());


            }
        });
        return view;
    }



    public void openDetailList(String...details)
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(c, ListDetail.class);
        i.putExtra("CREATOR_KEY",details[0]);
        i.putExtra("CONDITION_KEY",details[1]);
        i.putExtra("PLACE_KEY",details[2]);
        i.putExtra("HOURS_KEY",details[3]);
        i.putExtra("AMOUNT_KEY",details[4]);
        i.putExtra("JOINED_KEY",details[5]);
        i.putExtra("CREATORUID_KEY",details[6]);
        i.putExtra("JOINEDUID_KEY",details[7]);

        c.startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

and here is my FirebaseHelper

```
public class FirebaseHelper {

    DatabaseReference db;
    Boolean saved = null;
    ArrayList<Bets> bets = new ArrayList<>();


    public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
        this.db = db;
    }


    public Boolean save(Bets bets)
    {
        if(bets == null)
        {

            saved = false;
        }
        else {

            try {
                db.child("bets").push().setValue(bets);
                saved = true;
            } catch (DatabaseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                saved = false;
            }


        }


        return saved;
    }



    private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {

        bets.clear();

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Bets bet = snapshot.getValue(Bets.class);
            bets.add(bet);

        }


    }


    public ArrayList<Bets> retrieve()
    {
        db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                 fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + databaseError);
            }
        });



        return bets;





    }


}
```

Saving/Inserting data works perfectly fine since I even have a sample data to show you after I added a bet but it doesn't populate the data.

```
{
  "bets" :
 {
    "-LAzYM9SA-8Sg0YgGqnv" : 
      {
      "amount" : 10,

             "condition" : "It will be sunny",

              "creator" : "Ginart",

             "creatorUid" : "MxQPvCjUIkahVSZk1y2stdCxeY32",

              "hours" : 2,

              "joined" : "Free",

              "joinedUid" : "",

               "place" : "New York"
    }
```

For some reason I think it reads the users data which is here

```
"users" : {
    "EbYtfLUPs7Vu2rvnExaOaqJ4J883" : {
      "balance" : 5,
      "bets" : 1
    },
```

Since every time I add a new user, the list view adds an Item to my list but with no data at all just my template and Android Studio shows me this

```
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for balance found on class Models.Bets
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for bets found on class Models.Bets
```

So it must be something wrong with the paths in my opinion. My Bets Model has no balance and bets variables.

Here is my OnCreate method where I'm using the retrieve() method in firebase

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);



Money = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Balance);
User = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Player);
betList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BetList);
addbet = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.AddBet);
addcreds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addCredits);
Money.setInputType(0);
User.setInputType(0);

betting = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
helper = new FirebaseHelper(betting);

mDatabase.child("users").child(current.getUid().toString()).child("balance").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        balance = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
        String b = String.valueOf(balance);
        Money.setText(b);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Money.setText("Error");

    }
});

mDatabase.child("users").child(current.getUid().toString()).child("bets").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        bets = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {


    }
});

User.setText(current.getDisplayName().toString());


//ADAPTER
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,helper.retrieve());
betList.setAdapter(adapter);

addbet.setOnClickListener(this);
addcreds.setOnClickListener(this);




}
```

Also, whenever I'm trying to change my reference to

```
betting = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bets");
```

I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: app.betme.betme, PID: 22814
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type Models.Bets
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                      at Utils.FirebaseHelper.fetchData(FirebaseHelper.java:67)
                      at Utils.FirebaseHelper.access$000(FirebaseHelper.java:21)
                      at Utils.FirebaseHelper$1.onChildAdded(FirebaseHelper.java:81)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.px.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Your FirebaseHelper class has a contructor parameter to set the DatabaseReference, could you show the part of your code where you supply that parameter? e.g. The calling activity that instantiates your custom adapter

Comment: Yes, I added that now.

Comment: Also, whenever I create a user, I am adding balance and bets values to them so they are set to the account by default. Maybe the EventChildListener catches that and that's why he gets balance and bets?

Answer (score 0):

It's not error, It's just a waring from Firebase that you should have methods to set data for `balance` and `bets`

Comment: That's what I taught also but I need Firebase to get the bets data instead of users